# How can i add a new progressBar to display overall downloads?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The code is working.
But, now I'm showing for each file the download progress in `progressBar1`.
But I want to add to the designer( added already ) `progressBar2` to show the overall download progress. How can I calculate it and display it in `progressBar2` ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DownloadFiles
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {  
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();    
        int count = 0;
        PictureBoxBigSize pbbs;
        ExtractImages ei = new ExtractImages();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            downloadFile(filesUrls);
        }

        private Queue<string> _downloadUrls = new Queue<string>();

        private async void downloadFile(IEnumerable<string> urls)
        {
            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                _downloadUrls.Enqueue(url);
            }

            await DownloadFile();
        }

        private async Task DownloadFile()
        {
            if (_downloadUrls.Any())
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += Completed;

                var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();

                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), @"C:\Temp\DownloadFiles\" + count + ".jpg");
                return;
            }
        }

        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Calculate download speed and output it to labelSpeed.
            Label2.Text = string.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));

            // Update the progressbar percentage only when the value is not the same.
            double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
            ProgressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());//e.ProgressPercentage;
            // Show the percentage on our label.
            Label4.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

            // Update the label with how much data have been downloaded so far and the total size of the file we are currently downloading
            Label5.Text = string.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's",
                (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"),
                (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"));
        }

        // The event that will trigger when the WebClient is completed
        private async void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Download has been canceled.");
            }
            else
            {
                ProgressBar1.Value = 100;
                count++;
                await DownloadFile();   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an int that stores the total number of bytes downloaded after each download (int bytesCompleted). In a separate method, loop through all the files you'd like to download and store that number in a separate int (int totalBytesAllDownloads). In progressChanged, report back to ProgressBar2 ((e.BytesReceived + bytesCompleted) / totalBytesDownloaded). I don't think it should be anymore complicated than that!

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev Could you show me please how to do it by code ? I didn't understand with the separate method and the rest. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this method which calculates the total amount of bytes needing to be downloaded (or modify an existing method, whatever you decide):

```
long totalBytesToDownload = 0;
List<FileInfo> files;
private void getTotalBytes(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    files = new List<FileInfo>(urls.Count());
    foreach(string url in urls)
    {
        files.Add(new FileInfo(url));
    }
    files.ForEach(file => totalBytesToDownload += file.Length);
}
```

So what i've done here is added a method that gets the total amount of bytes to be downloaded, and also created a variable that stores the file size for each file your trying to download, which will be used here in a minute.

First, in your Complete event, we need to create a variable that stores the number of bytes after each file download, which we will use later.

```
long bytesFromCompletedFiles = 0;
private async void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Download has been canceled.");
    }
    else
    {
        ProgressBar1.Value = 100;
        count++;
        bytesFromCompletedFiles += files[count - 1].Length;
        await DownloadFile();
    }
}
```

And finally, we can update the ProgressChanged event to finish your ProgressBar2:

```
private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Calculate download speed and output it to labelSpeed.
    Label2.Text = string.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));

    // Update the progressbar percentage only when the value is not the same.
    double bytesInCurrentDownload = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    double totalBytesCurrentDownload = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    double percentageCurrentDownload = bytesInCurrentDownload / totalBytesCurrentDownload * 100;
    ProgressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentageCurrentDownload).ToString());//e.ProgressPercentage;
                                                                         // Show the percentage on our label.
    Label4.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

    // Update the label with how much data have been downloaded so far and the total size of the file we are currently downloading
    Label5.Text = string.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's",
        (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"),
        (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"));

    //Let's update ProgressBar2
    double totalBytesDownloaded = e.BytesReceived + bytesFromCompletedFiles;
    double percentageTotalDownload = totalBytesDownloaded / totalBytesToDownload * 100;
    ProgressBar2.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentageTotalDownload)).ToString();
}
```

Hopefully, this works for you!

Comment: I'm getting exception on the line: ProgressBar2.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentageTotalDownload)).ToString(); first i got error on this line the error was on the part: Math.Truncate(percentageTotalDownload the error is: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'string'

Comment: Then i tried to change the line i changed the ToString() in the line to this: progressBar2.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentageTotalDownload).ToString()); now i don't get error but when running the program i'm getting exception on this line. The exception is: Message=Input string was not in a correct format. So i'm not sure how to solve the error and the problem with the progressBar2.Value line.

Comment: Try just putting ProgressBar2.Value = percentageTotalDownload. ProgressBar2.Value is looking for a double, but the way I formatted the code in the answer was formatted based off of how you formatted ProgessBar1

Comment: Ok i found that in form1 constructor i'm calling the method getTotalBytes like this: getTotalBytes(ExtractImages.imagesUrls); where imagesUrls is List<string> then i used a break point inside the getTotalBytes method on the first line: files = new List<FileInfo>(urls.Count()); i did continue and i see that files is 0. Empty. But urls is 399. The count of urls is 399. I can't find out why files is empty 0. Maybe since it's making new instance for the FileInfo List so that's why files is empty ?

Comment: I also noticed that you can't get FileInfo from url. It's not logic. So i think the whole thing in the method getTotalBytes is not logic.

Comment: I found how to do it. Should i answer my own question ?