# How can I create a List<FileInfo> from IEnumerable<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void getTotalBytes(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
     files = new List<FileInfo>(urls.Count());
```

For example urls count is 399.
But when I'm using a break point and hit F11, I see that the count of files is 0.

Comment: `var fileInfoList = fileNameList.Select(x => new FileInfo(x)).ToList();`

Comment: Example of url format from the urls: http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=eu&time=201701081930&ir=true

Comment: @RezaAghaei i'm getting exception:  URI formats are not supported

Comment: What i'm trying to do is explained in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527768/how-can-i-add-a-new-progressbar-to-display-overall-downloads The answer i got there gave me this problem in this method. The main goal is to get overall percentages calculation over webclient downloading files.

Comment: Should i add here also the details like i did in my other question ?

Comment: You can not get `FileInfo` from url.

Answer (score 3):

With `new List<FileInfo>(urls.Count());` you create an empty list with an expected capacity of 399. Therefore the count of files is 0.

The next step is to fill the list with actual `FileInfo` objects; e.g.

```
private void getTotalBytes(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    files = new List<FileInfo>(urls.Count());
    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
         files.Add(new FileInfo(url));
    }
```

or with Linq

```
private void getTotalBytes(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    files = urls.Select(u => new FileInfo(u)).ToList();
```

Comment: The first solution is what i have now no ? The second one the Linq give me exception: files = urls.Select(u => new FileInfo(u)).ToList(); the exception is: URI formats are not supported. it's on the part: new FileInfo(u)

Comment: FileInfo is used for information about files in the file system. Therefore the constructor of FileInfo expects a path with filename and throws an exception if a url like "http://something" is provied. If you want to get the size of web resources then you have to take another approach via web request (e.g. using the HttpClient).

Answer (score 0):

To literally answer your question:

```
var files = new List<FileInfo>();
foreach(var file in myEnumerableStringCollection)
{
    files.Add(new FileInfo(file));
}
```

However, your example's variable is 'urls' so I suspect you're attempting to do more with this than you explained.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is explained in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527768/how-can-i-add-a-new-progressbar-to-display-overall-downloads